# Cannot create Background Session without getting blocked on iOS Action Extensions

Tags: session, background, nsurlsession, ios-app-extension

I'm having problems initializing the background NSURLSessions without blocking the process and eventually throwing out error logs onto the console. My code is laid out like this

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration * configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"Something.something"];
configuration.sharedContainerIdentifier = @"group.Something.something.else"

self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:self.operationQueue];
```

Upon initializing, it blocks the process and 30 seconds later produces this error logs

```
2017-12-08 15:14:29.778309-0500 LibraryManagerTestExtension[1828:1032535] failed to open connection to AppleKeyStore
2017-12-08 15:14:29.778489-0500 LibraryManagerTestExtension[1828:1032535] Unexpected AppleKeyStore error: -536870212
2017-12-08 15:14:29.778844-0500 LibraryManagerTestExtension[1828:1032535] MKBDeviceUnlockedSinceBoot: MKBDeviceUnlockedSinceBoot fails with error(-1) for handle(0) with AKS error(-536870212)
2017-12-08 15:14:29.778915-0500 LibraryManagerTestExtension[1828:1032535] Attempting to create a background session before first device unlock!
2017-12-08 15:14:29.782429-0500 LibraryManagerTestExtension[1828:1032603] An error occurred on the xpc connection: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlsessiond was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlsessiond was invalidated.}
```

Here's my Info.plist settings

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RequestOpenAccess</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <string>5</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.app.non-ui-extension</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).LibraryManagerTestExtension</string>
</dict>
```

Any idea how to not make this happen?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I see that you're using the private com.apple.app.non-ui-extension NSExtensionPointIdentifier, which likely doesn't have a lot of access permissions by default. I'm in a similar situation but with Keychain access being blocked by the Sandbox. I also tried setting RequestOpenAccess to true, but my guess is that is limited only to the Keyboard app extension.